# SQL Server: combine multiple counts in one select

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am pretty new to SQL and am looking for help with the following:

I would like to count the number of items in column "esc" for the current + the previous 5 months and would like to have this done in one query. 
All I need is the number for each of this 6 months.

My SP (not working):

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112) + '01', 112)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112)),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log_Esc WHERE CONVERT(DATE, dateEsc, 120) >= CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE()), 112) + '01', 112))
FROM Log_Esc
FOR XML PATH('total'), ROOT('ranks')
```

Can someone tell me how I have to change this to get it working ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike

Comment: Please post the source table.

Comment: The column in question (dateEsc) is formatted as nvarchar(20) and contains date strings in the format yyyy-mm-dd. A column that could be used for the counting is EID (also formatted as nvarchar(20) that contains unique IDs). I only need the count, other data is not required.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working".  Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error message? What is your expected output vs. the current output?

Comment: @Mike - If the column is formatted like that, but isn't actually a `DATE` type, don't bother converting it in the query (it's wonderfully SARGable); just mess with the search parameters.  I **do** recommend permanently changing the column in the table, of course.  What version of SQL Server - you might have `LAG()` available, which you could then pivot to get this type of result layout.

Answer (score 0):

Two dates can be compared. GETDATE() returns a datetime object.
Just do your convertion on dateesc to a date or datetime type.
Also, don't forget to give alias to your columns.